# Have Superman or Supergirl ever tried to change history?

Tags: dc, time-travel, superman, supergirl

Superboy once ventured into the past and tried to make some changes to history, but found that compensating effects seemed to be at play and history was put back on track.

**Have Superman or Supergirl ever tried to change history?**

Comment: My guess: yes, lots of times.

Comment: @armadillo - Oh, jeepers yes. Bloody loads of times.

Comment: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11124/111244676/4761917-3570999-7518986993-16454.jpg

Comment: http://active-voice.net/jessplummer/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sgsat_ac295_6.png

Comment: Are you looking for any particular version (comics/movies/tv shows)? What counts as far as "history"? Superman rewound time a bit in the first Superman movie, but only a short while.

Comment: While maybe broad, a simple answer of yes with a couple examples would be a good answer. The OP is asking **if**, not how many times.

Comment: One of the tags was DC comics, realise the first film had Superman change history.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be willing to answer this question, given the complete ease by which image searching will reveal DOZENS of time travel episodes during the Silver Age, where Superman time traveled as easily as he crossed the street.

Comment: Superman may have been a frequent time traveller, but he doesn't seem to have gone back to *change* time many times (either he learned his lesson while as Superboy or there are other stories where he's tried to change time) Of the stories that Valorum pointed out, Superman seemed to go back in time to ensure Atlantis is saved but don't recall the Supergirl story (however think I've come across the name Luthor being changed to Thorul in other stories). It isn't too obvious if she's gone back in time to change history somehow (cousin warned her?).

Comment: The most obvious instance that I can think of is in *Superman* (the first movie) when his flying around the Earth causes it to go back in time, thereby changing history.

Comment: One example I remember was Superboy going back to try to prevent Lincoln's assassination.  Who should he encounter but grown-up Lex Luthor, hiding out in the past.  Luthor exposes Superboy to a chunk of Red Kryptonite which renders him incapable of motion.  Then when Lincoln dies right on schedule, Luthor realizes why Superboy was there and, despite being a villain, feels really bad about it.  (Superboy #85.  12-60.)

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt Yes, thanks I remember that story. I also seem to recall he tried to save someone in the civil war by placing a protective dome over him, but the soldier died (I think) from being bitten by a snake. I think Superboy came to the conclusion that it was impossible to change history. I wondered if future authors had forgotten this in the case of Superman and whether Supergirl had attempted to change the past.

Comment: @jim - As I recall, in the 1960s or 1970s, we learned that Lex had a sister, Lena, going under the name Thorul.I don't believe she was aware of the relationship initially.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt, I didn't see your comment and duplicated it. It was the first story I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly Supergirl tried to *change* history in the Action Comics #289 story "Superman's Super Courtship" by trying to get Superman to marry Helen of Troy. In the same story she contemplates that Cleopatra would be a good match for Superman but decides against interfering.

In Action Comics #274, "Supergirl's Three Time Trips" she appears to become *part* of history. For example the flag made by Betsy Ross is destroyed before George Washington can receive it and she creates a new flag.

Answer (score 0):

In Superhoy 85 (1960), Superboy decided to go back to 1865 and save Abraham Lincoln,  "changing history for the better."

Superboy tracked down a mysterious Mr. L who he figured must be Lincoln (just go with it). Mr. L turned out to be time-traveling Lex Luthor who just chanced to go back to that time and place. Luthor froze Superboy with Kryptonite and monologued so long that the assassination went on as usual.

To his credit, when he realized that Superboy came back to save Lincoln, Luthor burst into tears, proclaiming he was evil but not that evil.

Superboy may not have changed history but he had every intention of doing so.